# Why are 2D array elements not printed using *(a+1)?

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to accept and print 2D array using same integer lets take `i` and `j` but I'm not getting expected output. I'm using *(a+i) to print but it seem to print address!

Could some one please explain why it is happening like this ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[3][4];
    int i,j,k,l;
    printf("enter element\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                    scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("#####################\n"); 
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)       
    {

            printf("%d\n",*(a+i)); // what is *(a+i)? is it a[i]?
    }                             // how will it print all address??
}
```

Comment: `*(a+i)` is indeed, by definition, the same as `a[i]`. It's the `i`th element of the array `a`, which in turn is a one-dimensional array of 4 ints. In most contexts, an array name decays to pointer to its first element. That's how you end up printing an address. Apart from that, you have buffer overruns galore.

Comment: Your `scanf` loop goes out of bounds. Therefore your program will exhibit undefined behaviour regardless of what more helpful answers will explain about pointers and 2d arrays.

Comment: You're leaving the boundaries of your array in your loops/scanf. Don't know if you did that on purpose to play around with overflows.

Comment: Also note that you don't *really* have a 2D array at all. `a[1][4]` means it's a 1 by 4 array, which is pretty much one-dimensional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what is *(a+i)? is it a[i]? - ya it is. you can represent a[i] in many forms. those are *(a+i) or *(i+a) or i[a]. All are representing same memory location only.

In your program *(a+i) wont work with in the same function. Try to pass the array to another function and print there that time it will work. Try the following code-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print(int *a,int r ,int c)
{
        int i ,j;
        for(i=0;i<r*c;i++)
                printf("%d\n",*(a+i));
}
int main()
{
        int a[2][2];
        int i,j,k,l;
        printf("enter element\n");
        for(i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
                for(j=0;j<2;j++)
                        scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }

        printf("#####################\n"); 

        print(a,2,2); // calling my function here
}
```

But don't prefer this type of methods( *(a+i) for printing 2D array) in real time programming!

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is very simple you do this for arrays (*(arr+n)) arr is an address and n is the no 
of element address you search . If you want to search for addresses into a matrix you must first convert matrix address into a array address something like :
*(*mat+n);


And your code will be:

```
# include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[3][4];
    int i,j,k,l;
    printf("enter element\n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<4; j++)
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }

    printf("#####################\n");

    for(i=0; i<8; i++)

    {

        printf("%d\n",*(*a+i)); // what is *(a+i)? is it a[i]?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`*(a+i)` is definitely `a[i]`.

Many bugs in your code need to fix first.

1. Your array reading value goes to out of bound. You defined array by `int a[1][4]`  (room for **1*4 = 4** elements ) and you read **3*4=12** elements.
2. Also `a` points to entire 2D array and `a+1` point to next 2D array. So you need to access by pointing to first element of the array.

So basically valid access is

```
 a[0][1] = *( a[0] + 1 )
```

And

```
for(i=0;i<12;i++)   
      printf("%d\n",*(a[0]+i));
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way you can do what you are trying to achieve is to take a pointer to the base address of the 2D array, and then traverse the array linearly as you wanted to do.

Also, as already answered by Sathish, *(a+i) = *(i+a) = a[i] = i[a]

Here, in my solution, I have just added a pointer p which points to the base address of a, and because the 2D array is stored linearly in the memory, you can access it by incrementing the pointer p to the next array element.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a[3][4];
    int i,j,k,li, *p;
    printf("enter element\n");
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
            for(j=0;j<4;j++)
                    scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
    }
    printf("#####################\n");
    p = &a[0][0];
    for(i=0;i<12;i++)
    {
          printf("%d\n",*(p+i)); 
    }                             
}
```

Comment: Not necessary to assign p = &a[0][0];  12 times. one time is enough.